# Compatibility of "required"/"pattern" and "disabled" attributes during form submiting

Tags: html, w3c

I read following official documentation:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.pattern
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.email.attrs.required
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.email.attrs.disabled

but docs lack of description what happen when both these attributes was used during form submitting.

I expect that `disabled` elements bypass validation (`required` and `pattern`).

Or I should ask such question on W3 mail list?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, yes, disabled will bypass the other requirements. Such as disabling a required input is effectively not requiring it.